# htaccess mod rewrite rule causes stylesheet to not load

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, stylesheet

In my htaccess I put a few rewrite rules to change my ugly dynamic urls, into clean, static impersonators:

`mysite.com?content=content&content_att=content_att`
`mysite.com/content/content_att`

in `.htaccess`

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?$ ?a=b&content=$1&content_att=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ ?a=b&content=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The rules work just fine, but my issue is in the stylesheet not affecting the page at all. I am **not** using a relative path in my stylesheet link, and I checked the DOM tree which confirms the stylesheets are "loaded". It's weird, they're being found, but just not being applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following at the top of the `.htaccess` to prevent it from rewriting actual URL's:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
```